# Transparent encryption of data when moving to azure blob?

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to perform transparent encryption when we are moving data to azure blob and no need to have data encrypted while it is at rest?

I read about Azure key vault, but I believe that solution is for encrypting data at rest.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific encryption service. This would be up to your app.

You didn't mention which language you're using, but... the .NET and Java storage SDK's have client-side encryption built in. More info [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-client-side-encryption/).

Comment: David hit the nail on the head. To add a bit, the Azure Key Vault system is (optionally) integrated with the client library and is a solution for storing your keys securely.